# 了解 vs 明白 vs 知道 - what is the difference, and when should I use each one?

Tags: word-choice, difference

了解, 明白, and 知道 seem to be fairly synonymous in Mandarin, but there does seem to be some subtle differences between them.

What exactly is the difference? When should I use each one? Could you give me an example sentence to show when each of these terms would be the most appropriate?

Comment: 懂 is another one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

知道 means you just know something, you don't need to understand it.
了解, you understand it.
明白, you understand something, and have a clear idea of what it is about.

I think the order of them is: 知道<了解<=明白

for 了解, it can also means 'to investigate'. e.g 小白, 你去了解一下这事情怎么发生的.

Comment: Just an intermediate student, so I may well be wrong. But I have a feeling 明白 is not used so much in modern writing; maybe 了解 or some other alternative is used instead.

Comment: Quote:-  " 了解, it can also means 'to investigate'  My personal translation would be "to gain a better understanding"

Answer (score 0):

了解 also means to learn about, for example, 他去那个地方是想了解当地的风俗习惯。

Answer (score -1):

知道 = to Know, verb

了解 = to understand, verb

明白 = to be clear, adjective

Comment: That doesn't seem exactly accurate, given things like the well-known song lyrics, "明明白白我的心“ and sentences like "他对这个题目的了解..." in which 了解 does not behave like a noun.

Comment: I read "明明白白我的心“ as 我的心 is 明明白白, but you are right, 了解 can be used as a noun. good call.

Comment: Actually now I'm contemplating over this, I think 明白 can be used as verb too, as in 明白事理。

Comment: I've heard people asking, "你明白嗎？" to mean "do you understand?" in Taiwan.

Comment: lol and +1 at 明明白白我的心 in this context, @Terry Waltz =)

Answer (score -2):

知道 = Know

了解 = Know clearly

明白 = Know completely